# When using pararllel_for, result is not stable

Tags: c++, mfc, tbb

I learn TBB, and try using parallel_for function.

But result always change.

I use VS 2010 and language is C++, program is MFC Program.

Below is pseudocode + main code.

```
PushButtonFunction()
 call AfxBeginThread(Calculate())

Calculate
{
  SendMessage(WM_FUNCTION)
}

WM_FUCNTION link Play()

Play
{
  tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0,300),
    [&](const tbb::blocked_range<int> &r) 
{
  for( y = r.begin(), pos = 0; y < r.end(); ++y ) 
  {
    body code 1
    for( x = 0; x < 200; ++x, ++pos ) 
    {
      body code 2
    }
  }
}
)
    body code 3
}
```

I make breaking point in body code 2.(For check hit count)

Hit count is always different.(about 20000 ~ 80000, exact number is 60000)

I want know why this problem is occurs and how to solve problem.

Thank you for read.

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: It may be because you lack fundamental understanding of multithreading. If you are talking about "hit count" in the msvc debugger, I'm not even sure if that supports multithreading.

Comment: *"I want know why this problem is occurs and how to solve problem."* - What problem? You have described the expected behavior. @SvenNilsson: Do you have any reference that documents, that the breakpoint *hit count* would not work in a multithreaded environment?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Sorry. I will try it next time. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @SvenNilsson If that, Is this problem of VS 2010?

Comment: @IInspectable Sorry about it.
Problem is that Loop(body code 2) is exit without completing, go to next(body code 3).
I think about it "if Loop is completed, hit count is 60000. But hit count is always different".
So I want know cause of problem(Function call is wrong, my code is bad, VS problem, etc.)